# Woocommerce issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins

so due to a business change I have un-installed the woo commerce plugin and than re-installed it.
now on the all the products I create it throws me this error( becaus it is public on the webpage no matter what I do)

Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3829

Notice: in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3829

Notice: ID was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4137

the code at line 3289

```
* Filters whether to trigger an error for deprecated functions.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param bool $trigger Whether to trigger the error for deprecated 
functions. Default true.
 */
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
        if ( ! is_null( $replacement ) ) {
            /* translators: 1: PHP function name, 2: version number, 3: alternative function name */
            trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
        } else {
            /* translators: 1: PHP function name, 2: version number */
            trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! is_null( $replacement ) ) {
            trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.', $function, $version, $replacement ) );
        } else {
            trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.', $function, $version ) );
        }
```

and than at page 4137

```
@param bool $trigger Whether to trigger the error for _doing_it_wrong() calls. Default true.
     */
    if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'doing_it_wrong_trigger_error', true ) ) {
        if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
            if ( is_null( $version ) ) {
                $version = '';
            } else {
                /* translators: %s: version number */
                $version = sprintf( __( '(This message was added in version %s.)' ), $version );
            }
            /* translators: %s: Codex URL */
            $message .= ' ' . sprintf( __( 'Please see <a href="%s">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.' ),
                __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress' )
            );
            /* translators: Developer debugging message. 1: PHP function name, 2: Explanatory message, 3: Version information message */
            trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );
        } else {
            if ( is_null( $version ) ) {
                $version = '';
            } else {
                $version = sprintf( '(This message was added in version %s.)', $version );
            }
            $message .= sprintf( ' Please see <a href="%s">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.',
                'https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress'
            );
            trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s', $function, $message, $version ) );
        }
```

could somebody hint a possible resolution?